# Getting 500 error while sending the request through rest assured automation

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I'm getting 200 code when passing all required headers into postman, but when i try running through automation, i get an error 500

Below is the mentioned error message:

```
{"error":{"code":"500","message":"Internal Server Error","errors":[{"message":"[ISS.0086.9249] Missing Parameter: jsonString"}]},"request_tracking_id":"765666"}
```

I am expecting a solution. What do i need to change? Is it a server proablem? Is the request body the problem?

Comment: Considering it says `"[ISS.0086.9249] Missing Parameter: jsonString"` it looks like you're missing whatever that maps to `jsonString`